# Find out whether sound output is muted (ALSA with Pulseaudio)

Tags: scripting, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, alsamixer

I'm trying to look for a command that outputs `1` or `0` depending on whether I have my output muted.

I was trying this:

```
amixer sget Master
```

This is the output I get:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

Now the values change here accordingly (if I decrease volume, the percentage and the dB values change). However, if I head into `Pavucontrol` and mute my output on the 'Output devices' tab, the output of the command above stays the same. Literally nothing changes. But my sound indeed is muted.

What command should I use? Why doesn't that `[on]` change to `[off]`? Shouldn't it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a long search, I actually managed to find an answer. This might be helpful for others looking for something like this out there!

What you need:

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

This command has a line like this:

```
muted: no
```

And this `no` indeed does change to `yes`, when I mute my device. Perfect. I managed to strip the output using this command, should anyone need it:

```
pacmd list-sinks | awk '/muted/ { print $2 }'
```

Sorry for posting too soon, it seemed like I won't be able to find a solution anywhere.

Comment: What if you have multiple sinks? Similarly, if you do have multiple sources, the above code need more fine-tuning

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, for those like me who don't have PulseAudio or want to only use `amixer`, one solution is:

```
amixer get Master | sed 5q | grep -q '\[on\]'
```

returning `0` if unmuted and `1` if muted.

Comment: I used something similar and it doesn't rely on `sed`, `amixer get Master | tail -2 | grep -c '\[on\]'`. It returns 2 when muted.

Answer (score 2):

```
pactl get-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@
```

Outputs `Mute: no` if not muted, `Mute: yes` if muted.

Works even if you have multiple output. `@DEFAULT_SINK@` is the symbolic name of, well the default output. From `man pactl`:

> `get-sink-mute SINK`
>
> Get the mute status of the specified sink (identified by its symbolic name or numerical index).

Comment: The command was added in [PulseAudio 15.0](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Notes/15.0/#additionalcommandsforpactl).